# Render file with shortcode into a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am relatively new to php and wordpress and I would like to know how I can render a php file without the include statement.

For example if I have two files `plugin.php` and `component.php`

plugin.php

```
<?php
  add-shortcode('myshortcode', 'myshortcode-func');

  function myshortcode-func()
    // magic function that loads
    $result = LOAD('component.php');
    return $result;
  }
?>
```

component.php

```
<div>
   <img scr="<?php getimage() ?>" />
</div>
```

**NB**
I don't want to use include because I think it screws the rendering and insert the page in the flow when called.

Thanks for you help !

Comment: If include screws the rendering, then the problem is in your included file; not in the use of PHP's include statement... perhaps a newline after a closing ?>

Comment: but include directly include the file in the flow, right ?? here I don't want that. I want to have the content, to pass to a function and will include it itself. (This is a wordpress plugin for shortcode)

Comment: You may want to go up a level of the solution, and describe the overall problem you are running into.  There are likely two or three different approaches to consider.

Comment: I precise my question about the plugin I want to write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an output buffer:

```
function myFunc(){
  ob_start();
  include('component.php');
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Yes, they can overflow and print content prematurely if you load too much into it.  The buffer has a fixed size (defined in php.ini)

Comment: @Baptiste Pernet, you have just to be careful to close the buffers you open. I have never seen a buffer overflow, even when I use multiple buffers in a stack. The output of components is usually small in size anyway.

Comment: Can you wrap the component code in a function?  Then it won't echo until called.

Comment: For me  this code instead of simple return provided better results...

$out = ob_get_clean();
return $out;

Maybe it is PHP version related.

Answer (score 1):

How to:

```
$php = file_get_contents("component.php");
eval($php);
```

`eval` is very dangerous though and shouldn't be used in production.

If this is for production, I'd recommend using hooks/filters (see wordpress source code).  This lets you execute blocks of code on the fly, but is more constrained.

Comment: Yes it is for production... Why is it dangerous. What do you think of the method with an ouput buffer ? Can you send me a pointer to what is hooks and filter ? Thanks a lot

Comment: eval is dangerous because it's hard to know what all might be passed into it.  Wordpress uses hooks/filters to allow plugins, or modification of core behavior.  You could piggy-back off core Wordpress or write a simple hook system yourself.  Basically it's just an array, with function names stored under keys. They can be executed like `foreach( $hooks as $hook ) { $hook($data); }`;  That way, at least you know these functions only execute if attached in the top level php code.